# Compile a function in an SSDT PreDeployment Script

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2019

I have an unusual situation - first time!

I'm trying to write a **pre-deployment script** for an SSDT Project in Visual Studio, which will prepare a load of data for migration. There's a user-defined table-valued function (`TF`) in the new version of the database called `[MySchema].[MyFunc]` that will really help with the migration script... but it doesn't exist yet in the old database that will be upgraded and migrated. There are many other objects in the new version, but I just need to use this one to help with the migration. The function doesn't have any dependencies on any other new (or existing) objects, it's totally self-contained.

I'm hoping to compile `[MySchema].[MyFunc]` as part of the pre-deployment, so that I can use it. The function lives in `.\MySchema\Functions\MyFunc.sql`

I've attempted the following...

**ATTEMPT 1**

This fails with `Incorrect syntax near CREATE` (Note: `CREATE` is the first line of file `.\MySchema\Functions\MyFunc.sql`):

```sql
IF object_id('[MySchema].[MyFunc]', 'TF') IS NULL
BEGIN
    :r .\MySchema\Functions\MyFunc.sql
END
```

**ATTEMPT 2**

This fails with `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'` and `Incorrect syntax near ':' Expecting CONVERSATION`:

```sql
GO
IF object_id('[MySchema].[MyFunc]', 'TF') IS NULL
BEGIN
    :r .\MySchema\Functions\MyFunc.sql
    GO
END
```

**ATTEMPT 3**

Copy and paste the entire `CREATE FUNCTION` statement into my pre-deployment script:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [MySchema].[MyFunc]
(
    @p1 VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    some_col NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- some function code here
    RETURN
END
```

But this fails with `CREATE FUNCTION must be the only statement in the batch`. I've tried inserting `GO` before & after this, but I get similar results to ATTEMPT 2. I've also tried with `;` instead of `GO`.

**ATTEMPT 4**

I tried to use an [iTVF](https://database.guide/introduction-to-inline-table-valued-functions-itvf-in-sql-server/), but it didn't help

**ATTEMPT 5**

I considered, for a few brief moments, taking the code out of my function and just using it without a function... but I need to use that code around 20 times in the migration script. So I dismissed this option. It will produce a different result every time (due to changing parameters), so I can't just put it in a CTE or similar and re-use it each time.

**PLEASE NOTE**

Answers should be SSDT project specific. This isn't code being run in SSMS. It's in Visual Studio and will be run as part of a `Publish` process. If you're not sure what SSDT or a pre-deployment script is, please don't answer :-) Any answers not based on SSDT are irrelevant to this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: `ALTER/CREATE FUNCTION` and `ALTER/CREATE PROCEDURE` need to be statements in their own separate batch, i.e.: you can't wrap them in `IF` statements.

Comment: When I had to go down that rabbit hole (migrating data into the new schema as a part of SSDT deployment), I put all the migration logic into the post-deployment script. At this point, your function will be already available.

Comment: When I had to do this for some migrations-style scripts (similar concept though), I had to rewrite that into a dynamic SQL call that would create the function. It was a pain to do, but for something that will be re-used regularly, it makes sense. Because that had to be the first command in a batch, you may want to look at the option of creating it w/ dynamic SQL.    Alternatively, wrap your deployment in a larger script and call that before calling the publish action. Not fun, but sometimes necessary if the function doesn't yet exist, but is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting SQL Server 2016 or later two possible solutions come to mind:

1. in a seperate batch before including your function code try:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS [MySchema].[MyFunc];
```

2. revise the content of the `MyFunc.sql` file such that it starts with:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [MySchema].[MyFunc]
...
```

References:

- [DROP FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-function-transact-sql)
- [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have GO inside BEGIN/END. I don't see why Attempt 3 doesn't work, most probably because of other code you have in the same script. Normally you can create objects in the pre-script. Depending on the version of SQL Server you can either use `IF EXISTS` or change the code to `DROP` the function if it exists and then always `CREATE` it instead of the opposite approach you are trying to do.

Another way is to simply put data population logic to the pre-script itself. You can do something like:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SomeTable)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SomeTable ...
END
```

In such case you'll be able to re-run this script without duplicating the data.